# SqlCommand Parameters size confusion

Tags: c#, sqlparameter

I have the following line of code:

```
sqlcommand.Parameters.Add("@LinkID", SqlDbType.Int, 4).Value = linkID;
```

But, I'm slightly confused about the use of `size`.  Is this saying that its 4 bytes in size?  Or a length of 4 so `1234` is acceptable but `12345` is too big?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

For the types with fixes size you should omit this argument, simply:

```
sqlcommand.Parameters.Add("@LinkID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = linkID;
```

The size argument is only relevant for parameters with a type that can have variable size like `varchar`, `nvarchar` etc.

Comment: So... should you pass the size of the LinkID or the maximum size of the column?

Answer (score 8):

The size is 4 bytes for an int.

See [DbParameter class on msd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbparameter.size.aspx)n for more info. It is relevant because `SqlCeParameter` implements `DbParameter`

The following section is relevant:

> The Size property is used for binary and string types.
>
> For nonstring data types and ANSI string data, the Size property
>   refers to the number of bytes. For Unicode string data, Size refers to
>   the number of characters. The count for strings does not include the
>   terminating character.
>
> For variable-length data types, Size describes the maximum amount of
>   data to transmit to the server. For example, for a Unicode string
>   value, Size could be used to limit the amount of data sent to the
>   server to the first one hundred characters.

See this https://gist.github.com/1932766 for the implementation of the Size property.

Answer (score 2):

It is 4 bytes, 32 bits. It is a 32 bit integer.

Answer (score 2):

if you are going for int than i think therre is no matter what size of it.

so you code will be

```
sqlcommand.Parameters.Add("@LinkID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = linkID;
```

on for varchar,navarchar where the size is maater you need to speicify size in you .net code i.e in parameter